# Do I use "to", "of", "for" in the example text?

Tags: grammar

> "The passwords to my computer is short"

versus

> "The passwords of my computer is short"

versus

> "The passwords for my computer is short"

All of them sounds right and means the same thing to me. But I am guessing I am obviously wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I think all three are correct, though quite likely 'for' or 'of' are more common. For example, it's not unusual to see a phrase such as 'the admin password of my computer'.

However, please note that you've got the plural 'passwords' but you're then using the singular 'is' - that should actually be 'The passwords for my computer *are* short'.